# Have to stop operation taking place after sync

Tags: go-ethereum

Hey everyone its me again, so i need to know if i stop this operation(i don't know the name too because i'm a noob:D)that takes place after the sync due to construction to the house. If that is a problem or not? can i start back where i left off? here is a picture of where i'm at in this whole setup Geth process...[image]

Your answers are most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; it looks like you have a fully synced node; you will go out of sync (obviously) when you go offline, but when you come back on-line, your software will pick up where it left off. As long as you are online for long enough again, you will re-sync. Assuming you're not off for too long, that should be a rather quick process. Your computer only needs to download, verify, and store the blocks added to the blockchain since you went offline. In fact, you can go offline, come on briefly, go off, and come back, etc., before fully syncing without any bad effects.

Comment: awesome ! so you said i'm a fully synced node? does that mean i've been letting this thing run for 3 days for no reason then cause the "sync" process only took about an hour and then this process/operation started 3 days ago. am i ready for mining? or does this still need to setup?

Comment: also when i turn off the comp and run it again how do i go about starting off where i left off ? what code do i type in the CMD?

Comment: You can see that `geth` is now importing one block at a time roughly 15 seconds apart (with processing time <15s) and, more importantly, that the "number" column is up to date with respect to the chain height (according to, for example, Etherscan.io). This means that you are up to date. Each line is now telling you that your computer received a new block from the network. To resume node synchronization, you should be able to just run the same command as you did to start `geth` the first time.

Comment: In terms of setup for mining, you should make sure you have a copy of the account/etherbase keys `geth` is mining to. You will need to ensure the RPC port for `geth` is accessible to your miner(s) (probably fairly straightforward if it's the local machine). And, of course, you will need to set up your mining software.

Comment: ok check, i got the address written down, but i could use a link to a trusted mining software that can be used with geth to mine ethereum, because at this point i cant even find a place to download from, and i don't know how to setup proper, as i said i'm a noob :D..thank you for your help so far though it is appreciated.

Comment: If you're mining on a different machine from your Ethereum node (or keep your private keys offline), you don't have to place _that_ much trust in your mining software (unless you happen to be using your daily computer, too). As a "n00b" who is willing to put in some effort, your most trustworthy source is to compile your mining software from an established source such as https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum. Here be dragons of complicatedness. You can also try to a pre-compiled version from somewhere like http://cryptomining-blog.com/tag/ethminer-download/ and hope no secret code was added.

Comment: thank you so much sir! appreciate your time you took to let me know this. :D